# Error: Unable to find a match: xmlsec1-devel xmlsec1-openssl-devel On AlmaLinux:8

Tags: python, xmlsec, almalinux

I am getting below error while installing xmlsec on AlmaLinux:

```
#15 92.42   Building wheel for xmlsec (PEP 517): started
#15 92.65   Building wheel for xmlsec (PEP 517): finished with status 'error'
#15 92.65   ERROR: Command errored out with exit status 1:
#15 92.65    command: /usr/local/bin/python /opt/python2.7/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pip/_vendor/pep517/_in_process.py build_wheel /tmp/tmpKVierb
#15 92.65        cwd: /tmp/pip-install-8achWY/xmlsec
#15 92.65   Complete output (14 lines):
#15 92.65   running bdist_wheel
#15 92.65   running build
#15 92.65   running build_py
#15 92.65   package init file 'src/xmlsec/__init__.py' not found (or not a regular file)
#15 92.65   creating build
#15 92.65   creating build/lib.linux-x86_64-2.7
#15 92.65   creating build/lib.linux-x86_64-2.7/xmlsec
#15 92.65   copying src/xmlsec/py.typed -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-2.7/xmlsec
#15 92.65   copying src/xmlsec/constants.pyi -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-2.7/xmlsec
#15 92.65   copying src/xmlsec/__init__.pyi -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-2.7/xmlsec
#15 92.65   copying src/xmlsec/template.pyi -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-2.7/xmlsec
#15 92.65   copying src/xmlsec/tree.pyi -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-2.7/xmlsec
#15 92.65   running build_ext
#15 92.65   error: xmlsec1 is not installed or not in path.
#15 92.65   ----------------------------------------
#15 92.65   ERROR: Failed building wheel for xmlsec
```

**#15 93.86 Failed to build xmlsec
#15 93.86 ERROR: Could not build wheels for xmlsec which use PEP 517 and cannot be installed directly**

Answer (score 1):

since alma is binary compatible with CentOS you can do this :
dnf install -y https://vault.centos.org/centos/8/PowerTools/x86_64/os/Packages/xmlsec1-devel-1.2.25-4.el8.x86_64.rpm \